# How to add/remove onlick attribute for a button every 1 second using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this form:

```
<form>
   <button id="my_button" type="submit">
</form>
```

and I need add/remove (toggle) the onclick attribute every 1 second

SO it is changing from:

`<button id="my_button" type="submit">`

to:

`<button id="my_button" type="submit" onclick="extraFunction()">`

How to do that?

Comment: Why do you need to do this every second? For whatever reason you need this, it would be quicker to keep the click handler on the element, and handle the logic of allowing/not allowing the click in there.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I need to have the attribute in html like this: <button id="my_button" type="submit" onclick="extraFunction()">. The event listener is not enough ;(

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't toggle an inline `onclick` attribute. Bind an unobtrusive event listener, and have a separate timer that toggles a boolean that you can check from within your event callback:

```
var handleClick = true;

setInterval(function () {
    handleClick = ! handleClick;
}, 1000);

$('button').click(function () {
    if ( handleClick ) {
        extraFunction();
    }
});
```

---

If you *really* need to toggle the inline attribute, use this:

```
var $button = $('button');
var handleClick = true;

setInterval(function () {
    $button.attr('onclick', handleClick ? 'extraFunction()' : '');
    handleClick = ! handleClick;
}, 1000);
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Azs3A/), **but please don't use this!** Whatever you're trying to do, it could probably be done without the inline attribute.

Comment: I need to have the attribute in html like this: `<button id="my_button" type="submit" onclick="extraFunction()">`. The event listener is not enough ;(

Comment: @JimmyHendrikz - Why? Care to explain?

Comment: It's a complex form, where it's necessary for other elements and other actions. Your solution is nice, but I am interested in a solution using html attribute `onclick`

Comment: Thanks, but it's weird `$button.attr('onclick', handleClick ? 'extraFunction()' : '');` seems to be not working. Does `attr` works in all jQuery versions?

Answer (score 0):

here you go then :)

```
setInterval(function () {
    alert($('button').attr("onclick"));
    if ($('button').attr("onclick"))
    {
        $('button').removeAttr("onclick");
    }
    else
    {
        $('button').attr("onclick", "extraFunction()");
    }
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maximua/zJ3cr/